# uilabel shows "moving" while adding 

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my iPad application,

Somehow I have manged to add a UILabel on Navigation Bar as a title.

**While adding it to navigation bar** shows me moving for some offset.

Here "moving" means, 
It shows me some animation in a fraction of 0.1 second. (Adding activity , from some x,y to some x,y)

here is my code,

```
-(void)addnavigationcomponents:(id)sender
{

if(titleLabel)
{
    [titleLabel release];
    titleLabel = [[CustomLabelA alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,42,600,50) settag:1];
}

viewForLabel=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,600,96)];
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TAHOMA" size:34.0f]];

[titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

[viewForLabel addSubview:titleLabel];
self.navigationItem.titleView=viewForLabel;

titleLabel.text =calcname;

UIView *viewForButton=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,71,96)];

}
```

In `viewWillAppear`, I have added this code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(addnavigationcomponents:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.00];
```

I have done perform selector because simply rightin aa code for label and stuff is hidden behind my navigation background, so how could I do that.

How can I remove that animation.

Comment: Make all of your x and y coordinates for the various functions you use to make the label match up.

Comment: I have matched up simple alignments but still no effect.

Comment: What coordinates does it stop and end at? To me it looks like you set the center of the frame 3 times (once in `initWithFrame`, once in `setFrame`, and once in `setCenter`. You also change the frame after the label has been created. If you want to remove any visible changing of the label, then make your centers and frame match up.

Comment: @Dustin: I have removed the center and frames set though it has not much eeffect.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to do here:

1. Don't call this on "viewWillAppear" - you want this code to be executed on "viewDidLoad".
2. Refrain from performing a selector after delay of 0.0 - if it's the only way this works then it shouldn't be done in this manner at all.
3. As best practice, set the text before adding it as a subview to the "viewForLabel".

Comment: Is anything else going on while this is added? Where in the view controller lifecycle is this code placed?

Comment: In view will Appear [self performSelector:@selector(addnavigationcomponents:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.00];

Comment: Try moving this to viewDidLoad directly (remove the call to an external method). By the way, something is seriously wrong if you're passing "self" as an argument although you're invoking the instance method "addnavigationcomponents" on "self". Also, I recommend using the lowercase Camel coding convention in the method name(s).

Comment: If remove the call then what happens that the components are hiding behind my navigation bar's background.

Comment: Then you need to find another way to do this - timing the method so that it works out by accident is not a generic approach. This means that you may see it fine on your simulator/device but someone else running a different device on another iOS version can get bad results (for example, the label may disappear).